# Angular new project - cannot read propertie

Tags: angular

I tried to create a new project using angular framework.
I entered the commands:

```
ng new test
```

and

```
ng serve
```

it complicated successfully but i got the following errors:
[image: Output]

I didn't get any similar errors yesterday. I don't understand why they are or what they mean. Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: I'd start with deleting node_modules and running `npm install`

Comment: You may have changed your node version ? Anyway, deleting/reinstalling node_modules is a good idea...

Comment: everyone is having the same issue in our company. might be a version issue. can you provide your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a global issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50961

A temporary solution could be:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Add the following lines to your package.json's dependency section:

```
    "@babel/generator": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/parser": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/traverse": "7.22.5",
```

3. Run `npm install`
4. Then `ng serve`